# connect to Minishift VM from host machine (Windows)

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox, minishift

I have created `minishift` env using comment:

```
 "minishift start --vm-driver=virtualbox -v5 --show-libmachine-logs --alsologtostderr"
```

Now I have the console for minishift working.

I have to make some changes to `master node config files a`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To connect to the Minishift VM you can use `minishift ssh` command which will connect the cmd/Powershell session to the shell on the VM. You can then do whatever changes you want to do using `sudo`, which is on the VM password-less. However please note that changing the VM directly is not recommended and might cause problems.

To make the changes to the master node you could also use `minishift openshift config` command which provides way to alter OpenShift's cluster configuration. In general using this command with combination with `oc adm` is advised for most users as it should be more secure and robust solution than altering the configs directly in the VM.